# What are the 2 general systems to understand the whole natural world?

Tags: natural-selection, sexual-selection, selection, artificial-selection

In Graham Bell's book *[Selection](http://www.oxfordscholarship.com/view/10.1093/acprof:oso/9780198569725.001.0001/acprof-9780198569725-miscMatter-7)*, it's written:

> To some it may be a cause of regret that the natural world cannot be understood in terms of a single set of rules and laws, but at least, so far as we know, the whole of the natural world can be understood in terms of just two general systems, and no more. This book is an account of one of these, in the context of biological systems. It is an account of the Second Science

The first system or process is *Selection*. What is the second?

Comment: I wonder if it might be genetic drift?

Comment: The categorization of the entire of knowledge regarding the natural world is sexy but the categories aren't necessarily natural ([wiki > natural category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_kind)). 99.999% of scientists (me included even if I am an evolutionary biologist) would disagree to consider the the process of selection would hold half of the knowledge we have about the natural world. It does not even hold half of our knowledge in evolutionary biology!

Comment: In any case, whether his saying makes sense (or even whether the question of what he says) is a matter of opinion and is therefore off-topic.

Comment: If you are interested the philosophical discussion of how to divide our knowledge about the natural world, you can give it a try on Philosophy.SE (once you figured what the second general system is) Or you could try to chat about it with Graham Bell directly over a coffee as you both work in the same University!

Comment: @Remi.b thanks for your comments. While you are there, you could ask what Dolph thinks about it? :D I still think that this is a legit question and that it could be interesting to discuss. I guess that saying it's a general question about biology or philosophical question is an opinion too. Maybe if the question is: what are the 2 general systems to understand the natural world in biology might be more biology related? What's your advice on how to edit that question so that it fits, in your opinion, into this forum?

Comment: @M.Beausoleil As a rule, questions that evoke discussion aren't good SE questions. The point is to produce questions that have an answer that can be accepted as the best answer out of fact and presentation, not out of rhetoric.

Comment: On reading the rest of that passage via google books I think you and others are simply interpreting it wrong. He isn't saying Selection is one of the two ways to understand the world he is saying that one approach is to reduce to basic principles, like physics and chemistry, and the other is that this isn't possible. He is saying his book is one example of an attempt to understand something that cannot be reduced to basic principles alone.